# Create .class files from the command line with package dependencies

Tags: java, command-line, javac, .class-file

So I have the following structure:

```
HelloWorld
  -> Package1
      -> Class1.java
  -> Package2
      -> Class2.java
```

I am trying to complile Class2.java from the command line using:

```
javac -classpath ../equinox.jar Package2/Class2.java
```

But i keep on getting the error : `package Package1 does not exist`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would use an IDE or a build system like maven (or both)  Trying to compile a program on the command line doesn't scale and is needlessly complicated for even one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the current directory in the compilation path

```
javac -classpath ../equinox.jar:. Package2/Class2.java
```

Explanation: because the `-classpath` argument is used the current directory is no longer automatically used in the classpath so needs to be added explicitly.

See the [Java programming language compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for a full description of all command line options